# Custom grid, on click open only one content

Tags: jquery, grid, click, toggle

I'm building a custom grid - which is fine, but I'm having some issue to display the content.

What I'm trying to achieve is to toggle the item link to the object.

( What I mean, in my first row, I have item A, item B, item C) On click on item A, it should toggle the content of ITEM A. On click of item B, toggle content of content B, etc)

Right now, if I click on the item 1, it toggles the content of item 1, item 2 and item 3 at the same time.

Also, if I click on item 2, it doesn't toggle any content.

Here you can see the code and live: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNRBQX

I put the toggle function in case here but better to see the codepend:

```
//** HERE THE TOGGLE FUNCTION **/

$('#toggle').click(function() {
$('.toggle').slideToggle('slow');
return false;
});

$('#toggle').click(function() {

$('.toggleaction').addClass('current');

       if($('.toggleaction').hasClass('current')){

     $('.hide').addClass('displayon');
 $('img.grayscale.oui').toggleClass('color');

 }

});

/** CLOSING TOGGLE **/

$('#toggle-close').click(function() {
$('.toggle').slideToggle('slow');
return false;
});

$('#toggle-close').click(function() {

$('.toggleaction').toggleClass('current');

       if($('.toggleaction').toggleClass('current')){

    $('.hide').toggleClass('displayon');
 $('img.grayscale').removeClass('color');

 }


});
```

If anybody has any highlite, it would be wonderful !!!

Thanks a lot for all your help !

Answer (score 0):

don't know if this is what you need, I made it pretty simple so that you can understand what the code is doing and build whatever you need based on that :-) Hope this solves your problem. Here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kymera28/a7c38r5q/1/).

```
$('.header').click(function(){
    $('.content').slideUp();
    if($(this).next('.content').is(':hidden')){
        $(this).next('.content').slideDown()
    }
})
```

Basically what this is doing is hiding all the ".content" elements of all the accordion tabs and displaying the clicked  accordion's content only if it isn't visible (otherwise it would close and open again).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time. Hmmm not really, as my content of the item is "outside" the item ( this to have the content fullwidht in the grid) it is not going to work with your code  I think .. . :/ (  the fiddle doenst seem to work by the way). Thanks for your time, if you hav eany other solution in mind let me know :)